# How to set the moving element to four ways repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to miniplate this code taken from https://www.technologies4.me/ to a slightly different way to play a game I called it "NavigateToEnd".
I have a set of buttons Up,Down,Left,Right and Start so you pre plans the moving element how many rights, lefts, ups and downs it would do on the path before reaching the end.

My problem is it doesn't reach the end and starts moving the wrong way. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong.

```js
var rightSteps = 0;
var leftSteps = 0;
var upSteps = 0;
var downSteps = 0;
var ctx = null;
// 1's are path 
var gameMap = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
];
var tileW = 40,
  tileH = 40; //w and h of each tile
var mapW = 10,
  mapH = 10; //10 by 10
var currentSecond = 0,
  frameCount = 0,
  framesLastSecond = 0,
  lastFrameTime = 0;

var keyPad = { //Pad keys
  "left": false,
  "right": false,
  "up": false,
  "down": false
};

var player = new Character();

function Character() {
  this.tileFrom = [1, 1];
  this.tileTo = [1, 1];
  this.timeMoved = 0;
  this.dimensions = [30, 30];
  this.position = [45, 45];
  this.delayMove = 700;
}
Character.prototype.placeAt = function(x, y) {
  this.tileFrom = [x, y];
  this.tileTo = [x, y];
  this.position = [((tileW * x) + ((tileW - this.dimensions[0]) / 2)),
    ((tileH * y) + ((tileH - this.dimensions[1]) / 2))
  ];
};
Character.prototype.processMovement = function(t) {
  if (this.tileFrom[0] == this.tileTo[0] &&
    this.tileFrom[1] == this.tileTo[1]) {
    return false;
  }

  if ((t - this.timeMoved) >= this.delayMove) {
    this.placeAt(this.tileTo[0], this.tileTo[1]);
  } else {
    this.position[0] = (this.tileFrom[0] * tileW) +
      ((tileW - this.dimensions[0]) / 2);
    this.position[1] = (this.tileFrom[1] * tileH) +
      ((tileH - this.dimensions[1]) / 2);

    if (this.tileTo[0] != this.tileFrom[0]) {
      var diff = (tileW / this.delayMove) * (t - this.timeMoved);
      this.position[0] += (this.tileTo[0] < this.tileFrom[0] ? 0 - diff :
        diff);
    }
    if (this.tileTo[1] != this.tileFrom[1]) {
      var diff = (tileH / this.delayMove) * (t - this.timeMoved);
      this.position[1] += (this.tileTo[1] < this.tileFrom[1] ? 0 - diff :
        diff);
    }

    this.position[0] = Math.round(this.position[0]);
    this.position[1] = Math.round(this.position[1]);
  }
  return true;
}

function toIndex(x, y) {
  return ((y * mapW) + x);
}

window.onload = function() {
  ctx = document.getElementById('game').getContext("2d");
  requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
  ctx.font = "bold 10pt sans-serif";

  document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", function() {
    rightSteps++;
    document.getElementById("rightcount").innerHTML = rightSteps; // Output of click counts
  });
  document.getElementById("down").addEventListener("click", function() {
    downSteps++;
    document.getElementById("downcount").innerHTML = downSteps;
  });
  document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click", function() {
    leftSteps++;
    document.getElementById("leftcount").innerHTML = leftSteps;
  });
  document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("click", function() {
    upSteps++;
    document.getElementById("upcount").innerHTML = upSteps;
  });
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {

    if (rightSteps > 0) {
      keyPad["right"] = true;
    }
    if (downSteps > 0) {
      keyPad["down"] = true;
    }
    if (leftSteps > 0) {
      keyPad["left"] = true;
    }
    if (upSteps > 0) {
      keyPad["up"] = true;
    }

  });
};

function drawGame() {
  if (ctx == null) {
    return;
  }

  var currentFrameTime = Date.now();
  var timeElapsed = currentFrameTime - lastFrameTime;

  var sec = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  if (sec != currentSecond) {
    currentSecond = sec;
    framesLastSecond = frameCount;
    frameCount = 1;
  } else {
    frameCount++;
  }

  if (!player.processMovement(currentFrameTime)) {

    if (keyPad["right"] &&
      player.tileFrom[0] < (mapW - 1) &&
      gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0] + 1, player.tileFrom[1])] == 1) {
      player.tileTo[0] += 1;
      rightSteps--;
      if (rightSteps <= 0)
        keyPad["right"] = false;
      document.getElementById("rightcount").innerHTML = rightSteps;
    } else if (keyPad["down"] &&
      player.tileFrom[1] < (mapH - 1) &&
      gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0], player.tileFrom[1] + 1)] == 1) {
      player.tileTo[1] += 1;
      downSteps--;
      if (downSteps <= 0)
        keyPad["down"] = false;
      document.getElementById("downcount").innerHTML = downSteps;
    } else if (keyPad["left"] &&
      player.tileFrom[0] > 0 &&
      gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0] - 1, player.tileFrom[1])] == 1) {
      player.tileTo[0] -= 1;
      leftSteps--;
      if (leftSteps <= 0)
        keyPad["left"] = false;
      document.getElementById("leftcount").innerHTML = leftSteps;
    } else if (keyPad["up"] &&
      player.tileFrom[1] > 0 &&
      gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0], player.tileFrom[1] - 1)] == 1) {
      player.tileTo[1] -= 1;
      upSteps--;
      if (upSteps <= 0)
        keyPad["up"] = false;
      document.getElementById("upcount").innerHTML = upSteps;
    }

    if (player.tileFrom[0] != player.tileTo[0] ||
      player.tileFrom[1] != player.tileTo[1]) {
      player.timeMoved = currentFrameTime;
    }
  }

  // Creating tiles
  for (var y = 0; y < mapH; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < mapW; ++x) {
      switch (gameMap[((y * mapW) + x)]) {
        case 0:
          ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";
          break;
        default:
          ctx.fillStyle = "white";
          break;
      }
      ctx.strokeStyle = "lightgray"; // Grid line colour
      ctx.strokeRect(x * tileW, y * tileH, tileW, tileH); //Creating a grid 
      ctx.fillRect(x * tileW, y * tileH, tileW, tileH);
    }
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "red"; //Moving element's color
  ctx.fillRect(player.position[0], player.position[1],
    player.dimensions[0], player.dimensions[1]);

  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";

  lastFrameTime = currentFrameTime;
  requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
}
```

```html
<a id="upcount">0</a>&nbsp;
<a id="downcount">0</a>&nbsp;
<a id="leftcount">0</a>&nbsp;
<a id="rightcount">0</a><br>

<button id="up"><img src="images/im_up.png" title="Up"></button>
<button id="down"><img src="images/im_down.png" title="Down"></button>
<button id="left"><img src="images/im_left.png" title="Left"></button>
<button id="right"><img src="images/im_right.png" title="Right"></button>
<button id="reset" onclick="window.location.reload();"><img src="images/im_reset.png" title="Reset"></button>
<button id="start" title="Start">Start</button>
<br>
<p></p>

<canvas id="game" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Now I understand the `*Steps` variables and the loop based on `requestAnimationFrame` and `drawGame`. However, one thing that draws my attention is that you can't go RIGHT > DOWN > LEFT > DOWN > RIGHT, because your code will always try to go RIGHT > RIGHT first (you are not saving the chronological order). Also, it looks like the Character class is an important piece, and it's not easy to read. Please explain a little bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right, your mistake is that you are not saving the user inputs in chronological order. I have added a `moves` queue to replace the `*Steps` variables in the `if`s of the `drawGame` function (the `*Steps` variables are not removed completely because we still need to update the numbers above the map). Here is how the queue works (it's nothing more than an array):

```
> | moves = []
< | []
> | moves.unshift("right") // enqueue
< | 1
> | moves.unshift("down") // enqueue
< | 2
> | moves.unshift("down") // enqueue
< | 3
> | moves
< | ["down", "down", "right"]
> | moves.pop() // dequeue
< | "right"
> | moves.pop() // dequeue
< | "down"
> | moves.pop() // dequeue
< | "down"
> | moves
< | []
```

Note that you can enqueue moves to the `moves` queue from the browser console during the processing of the game loop. For example, click "start" without clicking any other button, then, in your browser console, write `moves.unshift("right")`, `moves.unshift("down")`, etc (not working with StackOverflow code snippet, try with your local file). Enjoy :-)

```js
var ctx = null;
var gameMap = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
];
var 
  mapW = 10,
  mapH = 10,
  tileW = 40,
  tileH = 40,
  currentSecond = 0,
  frameCount = 0,
  framesLastSecond = 0,
  lastFrameTime = 0,
  upSteps = 0,
  downSteps = 0,
  rightSteps = 0,
  leftSteps = 0,
  startClicked = false
;
var keyPad = {
  "left"  : false,
  "right" : false,
  "up"    : false,
  "down"  : false
};
var player = new Character(
  [0, 1] // initial tile
);
var
  moves = [],
  currentMove = null
;

function Character(tile) {
  this.timeMoved = 0;
  this.delayMove = 700;
  this.dimensions = [30, 30];
  this.tileFrom = [tile[0], tile[1]];
  this.tileTo = [tile[0], tile[1]];
  this.position = [
    tileW * tile[0] + (tileW - this.dimensions[0]) / 2,
    tileW * tile[1] + (tileH - this.dimensions[0]) / 2
  ];
}
Character.prototype.isMoving = function() {
  return (
    this.tileFrom[0] != this.tileTo[0]
    || this.tileFrom[1] != this.tileTo[1]
  );
}
Character.prototype.updatePosition = function(x, y) {
  this.position = [
    tileW * x + (tileW - this.dimensions[0]) / 2,
    tileH * y + (tileH - this.dimensions[1]) / 2
  ];
}
Character.prototype.placeAt = function(x, y) {
  this.tileFrom = [x, y];
  this.tileTo = [x, y];
  this.updatePosition(x, y);
};
Character.prototype.processMovement = function(t) {
  if ((t - this.timeMoved) >= this.delayMove) {
    this.placeAt(
      this.tileTo[0],
      this.tileTo[1]
    );
  } else {
    this.updatePosition(
      this.tileFrom[0],
      this.tileFrom[1]
    );
    if (this.tileTo[0] != this.tileFrom[0]) {
      var diff = (
        // horizontal speed
        tileW / this.delayMove
      ) * (
        // elapsed time
        t - this.timeMoved
      );
      this.position[0] += (
        this.tileTo[0] < this.tileFrom[0] ? -diff : diff
      );
    }
    if (this.tileTo[1] != this.tileFrom[1]) {
      var diff = (
        // vertical speed
        tileH / this.delayMove
      ) * (
        // elapsed time
        t - this.timeMoved
      );
      this.position[1] += (
        this.tileTo[1] < this.tileFrom[1] ? -diff : diff
      );
    }
    this.position[0] = Math.round(this.position[0]);
    this.position[1] = Math.round(this.position[1]);
  }
}

function toIndex(x, y) {
  return y * mapW + x;
}
function getEl(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
function onClick(id, f) {
  getEl(id).addEventListener("click", f);
}

window.onload = function() {
  ctx = getEl('game').getContext("2d");
  requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
  ctx.font = "bold 10pt sans-serif";
  onClick("right", function() {
    moves.unshift("right");
    getEl("rightcount").innerHTML = ++rightSteps;
  });
  onClick("down", function() {
    moves.unshift("down");
    getEl("downcount").innerHTML = ++downSteps;
  });
  onClick("left", function() {
    moves.unshift("left");
    getEl("leftcount").innerHTML = ++leftSteps;
  });
  onClick("up", function() {
    moves.unshift("up");
    getEl("upcount").innerHTML = ++upSteps;
  });
  onClick("start", function() {
    startClicked = true;
  });
};

function drawGame() {
  if (ctx == null) {
    return;
  }
  var currentFrameTime = Date.now();
  var timeElapsed = currentFrameTime - lastFrameTime;
  var sec = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  if (sec != currentSecond) {
    currentSecond = sec;
    framesLastSecond = frameCount;
    frameCount = 1;
  } else {
    frameCount++;
  }
  if (player.isMoving()) {
    player.processMovement(currentFrameTime);
  } else {
    if (startClicked) {
      // read next move from the queue
      currentMove = moves.pop();
    }
    if (
      currentMove === "right"
      && player.tileFrom[0] < (mapW - 1)
      && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0] + 1, player.tileFrom[1])] == 1
    ) {
      player.tileTo[0] += 1;
      getEl("rightcount").innerHTML = --rightSteps;
    } else if (
      currentMove === "down"
      && player.tileFrom[1] < (mapH - 1)
      && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0], player.tileFrom[1] + 1)] == 1
    ) {
      player.tileTo[1] += 1;
      getEl("downcount").innerHTML = --downSteps;
    } else if (
      currentMove === "left"
      && player.tileFrom[0] > 0
      && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0] - 1, player.tileFrom[1])] == 1
    ) {
      player.tileTo[0] -= 1;
      getEl("leftcount").innerHTML = --leftSteps;
    } else if (
      currentMove === "up"
      && player.tileFrom[1] > 0
      && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0], player.tileFrom[1] - 1)] == 1
    ) {
      player.tileTo[1] -= 1;
      getEl("upcount").innerHTML = --upSteps;
    }
    if (player.isMoving()) {
      player.timeMoved = currentFrameTime;
    }
  }
  for (var y = 0; y < mapH; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < mapW; ++x) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = "lightgray";
      switch (gameMap[((y * mapW) + x)]) {
        case 0:
          ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";
          break;
        default:
          ctx.fillStyle = "white";
          break;
      }
      ctx.strokeRect(
        x * tileW,
        y * tileH,
        tileW,
        tileH
      );
      ctx.fillRect(
        x * tileW,
        y * tileH,
        tileW,
        tileH
      );
    }
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(
    player.position[0],
    player.position[1],
    player.dimensions[0],
    player.dimensions[1]
  );
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
  lastFrameTime = currentFrameTime;
  requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
}
```

```html
<a id="upcount">0</a>&nbsp;
<a id="downcount">0</a>&nbsp;
<a id="leftcount">0</a>&nbsp;
<a id="rightcount">0</a><br>

<button id="up"><img src="images/im_up.png" title="Up"></button>
<button id="down"><img src="images/im_down.png" title="Down"></button>
<button id="left"><img src="images/im_left.png" title="Left"></button>
<button id="right"><img src="images/im_right.png" title="Right"></button>
<button id="reset" onclick="window.location.reload();"><img src="images/im_reset.png" title="Reset"></button>
<button id="start" title="Start">Start</button>
<br>
<p></p>

<canvas id="game" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```